# How to use POST method with Overpass QL and OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, overpass-api

I am using OpenLayers and Overpass QL with GET method to retrieve data from the Overpass server. Some URLs tend to be very long and hence get rejected by the Overpass server. To get around this, I am thinking of using POST method to query the Overpass server using OpenLayers. Is there a way to use POST method with Overpass QL (not XML) in OpenLayers? And if yes, what (syntax) goes into the **url** property of OpenLayers.Layer.Vector?

Answer (score 1):

The following solution works. Essentially, we take the parameters part of a normal GET request and put them as key value pairs inside **params** option and set **readWithPOST** property of **protocol** to true.

```
new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("hospital", {  
     strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX({ratio:1.0}),new OpenLayers.Strategy.Refresh()],
     protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
         url: "http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter";  
         params: {
              "data":"way['amenity'~'hospital|clinic|nursing_home|dentist|health$|health_post'](poly: '" +polyCoords+"');node(w);node['amenity'~'hospital|clinic|nursing_home|dentist|health_post'](poly: '" +polyCoords+ "'););out meta qt;"
         },
         format: new OpenLayers.Format.OSMMeta(),
         readWithPOST: true
     }),
     projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
});
```